# Spring Event is not getting published

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My custom event

```
public class TestEvent<E> {
    private E object;
}
```

Test class

```
public class Test{
    String message;
}
```

Class that listen to event has following listener

```
@Component
public class TestEventListener{
    // This listener works
    @EventListener
    public void testEvent(Test test) {
        logger.info("Test Received");
    }
    // This listener doesn't work
    @EventListener
    public void testEvent(TestEvent<Test> testEvent) {
        logger.info("Received");
    }
}
```

Code to publish the event

```
@Service
public class TestService{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public void sendMessage(){
        Test test = new Test();
        // Event is published
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(test);
        TestEvent<Test> testEvent = new TestEvent(test)
        // Event is not published
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(testEvent);
    }
}
```

Not sure what is wrong with the code but call never reaches my listener. I am using Spring 4.3.3 RELEASE

Comment: Please show us a complete example.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, I have added additional information

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile--`testEvent` isn't defined until after you're trying to publish it.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue. Code changes are as below:

```
public class TestEvent<E> implements ResolvableTypeProvider {
    private E object;

    @Override
    public ResolvableType getResolvableType() {
        return ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(getClass(),
               ResolvableType.forInstance(object));
       }
 }
```